# magento2 enable/disable value get and set value

Tags: magento2, system.xml

I have a module which shows value in the frontend, and from admin system configuration I want to disable that module options are coming like yes/no no I want to get that value of enabling/ disable module in magento2
[image]

as you can see in the picture that options are coming now I want to enable/disable module through these options
reference:https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html

Comment: in phtml file you want to get ?

Comment: yes in frontend options are coming from phtml file and i dont know how to get that value

Comment: what is your goal on this? please clarify things so that others can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create Helper file (Data.php) at this location `Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Helper/Data.php`.

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isEnable()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('helloWorld/general/enable', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Now Write this code in phtml file :

```
<?php 
$helper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data'); 
if($helper->isEnable()) : ?>

//WRITE YOUR CODE HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```

if you want to created field in value set then below file create 
 **etc/config.xml** in your extension

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <helloworld>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <price>100</price> <!-- here price is field name-->
                ---------<!--other fields-->
            </general>
        </helloworld>
    </default>
```

Comment: what is phtml file is for

Comment: Where you want to this file

Comment: i want to set the values in textbox like in front there are custom atrributes i want to set that price from backend there is textbox to enter the price

Comment: I don’t understand what you want  here firstly you want only value of enable disble field

Comment: You want to price add?

Comment: i want to do both things first enable disable columns and another set values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91741/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-ashish-ramchandani).

Comment: @AshishRamchandani check my updated answer it is working code for me

Comment: phtml file has wrong code

Comment: share me error which  error are you facing ?